# shake screen unlock

Tags: android

I am working on an app which will lock the screen on shake it consist of a main activity having two buttons to start and stop the app.
After that it is entering into a broadcast receiver which is checking whether the screen is on or off and then redirecting to a service.For first 3 or 4 shake lock and unlock its working perfectly after that its executing indefinitely.

The broadcast receiver i am using is..

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("Entered Broadcaste Reciever");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE

            wasScreenOn = "1";
           System.out.println("Check"+"Screen went OFF");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
            i.putExtra("screenstate", wasScreenOn);
            context.startService(i);
            System.out.println("jrkejhr keh");

        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // AND DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE

            wasScreenOn = "2";
            Log.i("Check","Screen went ONN");
            System.out.println("Entering to the service.................");
            Intent ScreenOnIntent = new Intent(context,UpdateService.class); 
            ScreenOnIntent.putExtra("screenstate", wasScreenOn);
            context.startService(ScreenOnIntent);  

        }

    }
```

and the service is.....

```
         public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
             System.out.println("Entered On Start");    


             data=intent.getStringExtra("screenstate");
             System.out.println("Data from Broadcast Receiver is"+data);
              mShaker = new ShakeListener(this);
                mShaker.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener () {
                  public void onShake()
                  {
             if(data.equals("1"))
             {
                 System.out.println(".............................................");


                PowerManager TempPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                PowerManager.WakeLock TempWakeLock = TempPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "TempWakeLock");
                TempWakeLock.acquire();
                final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibe.vibrate(100);

             }

              else
             {  
                  final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

                            System.out.println("The screen is off and is shaking.........");

                             vibe.vibrate(100);

                            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON); 
                            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
                            BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
                            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

                            ComponentName mAdminName = new ComponentName(UpdateService.this,LockActivity.class);

                                System.out.println("The Device  device admin enabled");
                               Intent  intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
                                  intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,"onEnabled");
                                mDPM.lockNow();
                                mDPM.setMaximumTimeToLock(mAdminName,0);
                                  intent.putExtra("force-locked", DeviceAdminInfo.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK);

   //                                       startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 
                        }

                  }
                });
         }
```

I want to execute this only once..if screen is  on execute once and put screen off,and viceversa..